# Why do the event args have no values when invoked with jQuery trigger()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, hammer.js, eventtrigger

I tried to use a trigger event.
If I trigger events independently with my hands, I haven't got problem and event args content all fields that I need.
If I use jQuery `trigger()` all works, but event args haven't got almost nothing.

```
<div id="dragDiv">
    <button id='dragButton' >tap</button>
</div>

$("#dragButton")
   .hammer({
        // options...
   })
   .bind("drag", doCall);

function doCall(ev){
    console.log(ev);
}

$('#dragButton').trigger("drag");
```

result

```
v.Event {type: "drag", timeStamp: 1357286124612, jQuery18306904058358632028: true, isTrigger: true, exclusive: undefined…}
currentTarget: <button>
data: null
delegateTarget: <button>
exclusive: undefined
handleObj: Object
isTrigger: true
jQuery18306904058358632028: true
namespace: ""
namespace_re: null
result: undefined
target: <button>
timeStamp: 1357286124612
type: "drag"
__proto__: Object
```

but I need:

```
v.Event {type: "drag", originalEvent: MouseEvent, position: Object, direction: "right", distance: 22.825424421026653…}
angle: -28.810793742973058
currentTarget: <button>
data: null
delegateTarget: <button>
direction: "right"
distance: 22.825424421026653
distanceX: 20
distanceY: -11
exclusive: undefined
handleObj: Object
isTrigger: true
jQuery18306904058358632028: true
namespace: ""
namespace_re: null
originalEvent: MouseEvent
position: Object
result: undefined
target: <button>
timeStamp: 1357286139160
touches: Array[1]
type: "drag"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: That's just how it is. For example if you trigger a click event programatically, the mouse does not actually have a specific position in that moment, so event object does not include mouse coordinates. I don't think there is much you can do here. It's similar in this case. You are not dragging any element in any direction, hence the handler does cannot know with which values to populate the event object.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct behavior because the missing properties are user-action dependant, or refer to the original user action that triggered the event, which are abviously undefined in case of triggering the event Via jQuery.

What are your expectations? If you exepct those values to be automatically filled, they can't because they need a criteria. If you know what values do you want in the event, or you can specify it at the time of tirggering the event, pass them this way:

```
var event = jQuery.Event("drag");
event.missingproperty = "myvalue";
event.anothermissingproperty = "anothervalue";
$("selector").trigger(event);
```

Answer (score 0):

For security purposes when you trigger an event with javascript it will register differently than if the user triggered the event. You will notice in your output there is an

```
isTrigger: true
```

Triggering the event yourself will always be different than when a user does.